# Elementor Pro Forms Validation for Zipcode

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, elementor, code-snippets

I'm using a simple form using Elementor Pro Forms. I'd like to filter out spam by only allowing zip codes starting with 91 or 92. Is there a code snippet I can add to help me do this?

I found this on [elementor developers](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/form-fields/field-validation/)

How would I adjust this to validate only these specific starting numbers.

Also, would this info be hidden from spam bots?

```
class Elementor_Test_Field extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Fields\Field_Base {

    public function validation( $field, $record, $ajax_handler ) {

        if ( empty( $field['value'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( (int) $field['value'] > 0 ) {
            $ajax_handler->add_error(
                $field['id'],
                esc_html__( 'The field must contain a positive number.', 'textdomain' )
            );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use custom validation hooks in elementor forms - and then probably use `str_starts_with('91', $str)`

Comment: See docs here : https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/form-validation/ - you are basically doing the same as the "validate email" string.